# ¿Como crear lista de objetos JSON?

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de crear una lista de objetos `JSON`, creando un `array` con las variables que utilizo, luego transformo el objeto a `JSON`, como muestro en el siguiente proceso:

```
 $jsonData = array(
          'OrdenHis' => $orden_temp[2], //# orden
          'OrdenSendMIS' => $orden_temp[2],
          'OrdenSendMIS' => $orden_temp[2],
          'Historia' => $data['DLHIST'],
          'IdExamen' => 'PE210223',
          'IdPerfil' => 'PE210223',


 ); 

 $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
```

Con el código anteriormente descrito, obtengo este resultado:

```
 "{"OrdenHis":"20000851","OrdenSendMIS":"20000851","Historia":"98435",
 "IdExamen":"PE210223","IdPerfil":"PE210223"}"
```

Lo que deseo es obtener este resultado:

```
[{"OrdenHis":"20000851","OrdenSendMIS":"20000851","Historia":"98435",
 "IdExamen":"PE210223","IdPerfil":"PE210223"}]
```

Alguien puede ayudarme para obtener el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregar tu Array key/value a otro array. de la siguiente manera:

cambia

```
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
```

por

```
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode([$jsonData]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un array de objetos JSON usa "array_push" sobre el array en donde se almacenan estos objetos:

```
$jsonData = array(
          'OrdenHis' => $orden_temp[2], 
          'OrdenSendMIS' => $orden_temp[2],
          'OrdenSendMIS' => $orden_temp[2],
          'Historia' => $data['DLHIST'],
          'IdExamen' => 'PE210223',
          'IdPerfil' => 'PE210223',
); 

 $jsonDataEncoded = array();
 array_push($jsonDataEncoded,json_encode($jsonData));
```

Comment: Pasa lo mismo que en otra respuesta. Devuelves un array con un ítem que es un json. Lo que se pide es un json que contenga un array de objetos

Comment: Lo que yo veo es un array con un elemento JSON adentro, como lo dice en el ejemplo: 

[{"OrdenHis":"20000851","OrdenSendMIS":"20000851","Historia":"98435",
 "IdExamen":"PE210223","IdPerfil":"PE210223"}]

Comment: si ejecutas el codigo y pones al final un print_r($jsonDataEncoded), el resultado es: `Array
(
    [0] => {"OrdenHis":null,"OrdenSendMIS":null,"Historia":null,"IdExamen":"PE210223","IdPerfil":"PE210223"}
)` Es decir, un array con un elemento de indice 0 y valor un json. Lo que se busca es: `[{"OrdenHis":null,"OrdenSendMIS":null,"Historia":null,"IdExamen":"PE210223","IdPerfil":"PE210223"}]`, que es un array de objetos

Answer (score 1):

Más fácil usando de nuevo con la función array():

```
$jsonData = array(
          'OrdenHis' => $orden_temp[2], //# orden
          'OrdenSendMIS' => $orden_temp[2],
          'OrdenSendMIS' => $orden_temp[2],
          'Historia' => $data['DLHIST'],
          'IdExamen' => 'PE210223',
          'IdPerfil' => 'PE210223',


 ); 

 $jsonDataEncoded = array(json_encode($jsonData));
```

Comment: Esto es erróneo. Aquí estas generando un array que contiene un ítem con clave 0 y valor el array codificado en json. Lo que se espera es un json que contenga un array de objetos.

Comment: Creo que leí mal la pregunta entonces, él sólo deseaba un objeto json y no un array cuyo único elemento fuera un objeto json.